# Using teams and styles in Worms for PS3

Tags: ps3, worms-2007

Worms for PS3 allows you to create customised teams and game styles. How do you actually use them in a game though?

Comment: Is this Worms classic or Worms Armageddon?

Comment: @wonea - neither, as far as I can tell. The game title in the PS3 menu and the main screen of the game both just say "WORMS".

Comment: There currently only two worms games (excluding the golf game) for the PS3 (Worms & Worms 2 Armaggedon), likely to be one of the two?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_downloadable_PlayStation_3_games

Comment: @wonea - Yep, it's just [Worms](http://au.ps3.ign.com/articles/968/968463p1.html).

Answer (score 1):

The customized team should be selectable when you create a game and pick teams. The style should be selectable when you create a game as well. The game type has to match the game style you created however.

Could you clarify what you mean by "see them in game"?

Comment: You hit it dead on Enigma. By see in game, I think he means by using his custom team in the game. I can't recall if you can only use custom teams in only custom matches, or if you can use them in the campaign as well.

Comment: I seem to recall (from a while ago) that it may be restricted to custom matches only where it would be a standard team vs team game. Some campaign levels are special in that perhaps only one worm is used so a team selection isn't possible. I may be getting that confused with one of the many other flavors of worms.

Comment: That's what I recall too, being just custom matches. I haven't played it since it first came out on Xbox Live (probably 5 years ago).

Comment: I've played nearly every variation since the original for 98. The old worms 2 allowed for some nice advanced weapons customizations like supping up a bazooka to have max impact force flinging worms everywhere with their little high-pitched screams. Funny stuff.